Is it correct to write $f(x,t) = f(x \pm vt)$?
Initially, the function $f$ is defined to be a function of 2 variables, $x$ and $t$, but it is then used as a function of 1 variable. This feels incorrect. Would it be better to instead write $f(x,t) = g(x+vt)$?

The second way is clear and correct.

Given the physical context in which this arises, $f(x,,t)=g_\pm(x\pm vt)$ can be contrasted with $f(x,,t)=\sum_\pm g_\pm(x\pm vt)$, but this subscripting of univariate functions means you can probably get away with changing the $g$s to $f$s.

It all depends on whether it is explained or defined, as any notation. If not, I don't see how anyone can consider it correct, even in physics you need to define your notation.

@Sil, much of these definitions, as in math, are such common language that everyone takes them for granted. In this case, what's happening is that there is some physical variable being represented by this abstract mathematical function. It is understood that while the mathematical functions are different, the physical variable is the same, so there's no need to switch notation. This maybe sounds strange to a pure mathematician but that's just because of our limited perspective, not understanding the context!

Yes, it is correct, assuming we are working in the context of physics.
From the perspective of pure mathematicians, this notation would be strange for the reason you said; mathematicians work with functions so it is important for a notation like $f$ to represent a single function object, and we do not want it to conflate a function $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ and another function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.
But this is correct notation from the perspective of physics. Physicists do not care about abstract functions in themselves; their notation emphasises the physical variables. For example, if $\psi$ represents some physical displacement, then the notation $\psi(x,t)=\psi(x\pm vt)$ just means that (1) the displacement $\psi$ depends on position and time, and (2) the dependency is only on the combination $(x\pm vt)$ (which is, up to a constant, the
"phase" of the wave). So there's nothing wrong with this notation in context.
To physicists, to use different notations would actually be "wrong", because it suppresses the fact that both mathematical functions represent the same physical variable.
Notation is all about communication. Does the notation communicate well, in the context which it is used, to the people it's supposed to communicate to? The answer is yes. A mathematician might not find it clear, but this notation is not meant for nor used by pure mathematicians.

For those who remain unconvinced, please see the comments beneath this answer on MathOverflow. Although that's not exactly the same problem as in this case, it is the same problem in principle: a question about whether some notation is "correct" when physicists use it differently than mathematicians. You will see that many (though not all) commenters have a general consensus that, in fact, the physicist's usage is perfectly legitimate. In my opinion, trying to insist the pure mathematician's way is the only "correct" one is arrogant and closed-minded.

This is a mathematics group.

And slang is slang, so: expressive yes but, as asked, not correct.

@Aruralreader as I explained, it is in fact correct considering the context it came from. A pure mathematician, with a pure mathematician's understanding of the notation, might not think it is correct. But a physicist, who uses mathematics in their work, would think it is fine. And the latter is the relevant context here. (Math SE is a site for math, and like it or not that includes math as used in physics; pure mathematicians don't have a monopoly on mathematical notation.)
